# Multi-statement table function to calculate monthly weekly and yearly the sum of payments between the start and the end date?

Tags: sql-server

The idea is to look through the index (Payment frequency id) and for example if the index is 1 then the total sum of payments needs to be calculate from the start to end date weekly for one year. If it is 2 then the total sum of payments needs to calculated monthly for the whole year. Right now I am creating individual tables to calculate them which is lengthy.

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(SUM(TP.PaymentAmount * 12), 'C2') AS Total_Payment,
    TP.PaymentFrequencyId
FROM [dbo].[Property] P
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OwnerProperty] OP ON P.id = OP.PropertyId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PropertyHomeValue] PHV ON OP.PropertyId = PHV.PropertyId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TenantProperty] TP ON PHV.PropertyId = TP.PropertyId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TenantPaymentFrequencies] TPF ON TP.PaymentFrequencyId = TPF.Id
WHERE OwnerId = '1426' 
  AND Date BETWEEN TP.StartDate AND TP.EndDate 
  AND TP.PaymentFrequencyId = 3
GROUP BY TP.PaymentFrequencyId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to Make @XAMT answer as Multi-Statement Table Value Function :**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateTotalPaymentWithFrequency] (
    @OwnerId int,
    @Date DateTime
)
RETURNS @returnTable
    TABLE (
        Total_Payment float, -- I dont know what is format C2
        PaymentFrequency int
        )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT Into @returnTable (Total_Payment, PaymentFrequency)
    SELECT 
        FORMAT(SUM(TP.PaymentAmount * 12), 'C2') AS Total_Payment,
        --TP.PaymentFrequencyId,
        Case
            When TP.PaymentFrequencyId = 1 then DATEPART(WEEK, Date)
            When TP.PaymentFrequencyId = 2 then DATEPART(MONTH, Date)
        End as PaymentFrequency
    FROM [dbo].[Property] P
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[OwnerProperty] OP ON P.id = OP.PropertyId
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PropertyHomeValue] PHV ON OP.PropertyId = PHV.PropertyId
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[TenantProperty] TP ON PHV.PropertyId = TP.PropertyId
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[TenantPaymentFrequencies] TPF ON TP.PaymentFrequencyId = TPF.Id
    WHERE OwnerId = @OwnerId 
      AND @Date BETWEEN TP.StartDate AND TP.EndDate 
      --AND TP.PaymentFrequencyId = 3
    GROUP BY 
        Case
            When TP.PaymentFrequencyId = 1 then DATEPART(WEEK, Date)
            When TP.PaymentFrequencyId = 2 then DATEPART(MONTH, Date)
        End

    RETURN
END
```

**It would be in Inline Table Value Function**

Answer (score 0):

I can help you if have more info about tables schema (ex: where is date field ?)
But this script should work :

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(SUM(TP.PaymentAmount * 12), 'C2') AS Total_Payment,
    --TP.PaymentFrequencyId,
    Case
        When TP.PaymentFrequencyId = 1 then DATEPART(WEEK, Date)
        When TP.PaymentFrequencyId = 2 then DATEPART(MONTH, Date)
    End as PaymentFrequency
FROM [dbo].[Property] P
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OwnerProperty] OP ON P.id = OP.PropertyId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PropertyHomeValue] PHV ON OP.PropertyId = PHV.PropertyId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TenantProperty] TP ON PHV.PropertyId = TP.PropertyId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TenantPaymentFrequencies] TPF ON TP.PaymentFrequencyId = TPF.Id
WHERE OwnerId = '1426' 
  AND Date BETWEEN TP.StartDate AND TP.EndDate 
  --AND TP.PaymentFrequencyId = 3
GROUP BY 
    Case
        When TP.PaymentFrequencyId = 1 then DATEPART(WEEK, Date)
        When TP.PaymentFrequencyId = 2 then DATEPART(MONTH, Date)
    End
```

For more info, I cal tell you that It's possible to make a condition for the aggregate function and the DATEPART is the key.

Two more things, What is the point of :

```
AND Date BETWEEN TP.StartDate AND TP.EndDate
```

And

```
FORMAT(SUM(TP.PaymentAmount * 12), 'C2')
```